# Como manter o banco de dados SQLite no Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sqlite, windows-10, raspberry-pi

Tenho uma aplicação rodando no Raspberry Pi com Windows IoT, mas toda vez que dou deploy em uma nova versão ou quando reinicio o Raspberry todo o banco de dados SQLite é apagado. Vi algo relacionado que ele por default cria bancos temporários. Como manter os dados permanentemente?

**[Atualização]**
Utilizei exatamente o tutorial do link a seguir http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/Using-SQLITE-in-Windows-10-IoT-Core-Insider-Preview/

Comment: Não sei se há alguma diferença no SQLite que está usando, mas no padrão isso não procede. Também pode ser o jeito que está fazendo. Ou algo relacionado o R Pi. De qualquer forma é difícil ajudar sem detalhes.

Comment: @bigown atualizei com o link do tutorial que utilizei. Fiz tudo exatamente igual.